# Problem with conditional distribution of two variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent random variables with the exponential distribution and expected value equal to $1$. How to obtain distribution $\operatorname{Pr}\left(\dfrac{X_1}{X_2}|X_2=x_2\right)$?

I have evaluated $X_1/X_2$ distribution myself and it is $f_{X_1/X_2}(t)=\dfrac{1}{(1+t)^2}.$

Primarily I wanted to use the formula
$$
f_{X|Y=y}=\dfrac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}, \ f_Y(y)\neq 0,
$$
but the problem is in fact, that our variables ($X_1/X_2$ and $X_2$) aren't independent.

Any advices are going to be helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very useful rule in probability theory, which states that the conditional distribution of $f(X_1,X_2)$ conditioned on $X_2=x_2$ is simply the conditional distribution of $f(X_1,x_2)$ conditioned on $X_2=x_2$ for any measurable function $f$.

This means that
$$\frac{X_1}{X_2} \: | \: X_2=x_2 \quad \sim \quad\frac{X_1}{x_2} \: | \: X_2=x_2 \quad \sim \quad \frac{X_1}{x_2}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very helpful statement in this case.

Comment: So how is it going to look like exactly in my case? Frankly I don't know the distribution of $\dfrac{X_1}{x_2}$. Only of  $\dfrac{X_1}{X_2}$. I'm guessing it's not the same.

Comment: Let $x_2>0$ be a fixed real number. Then $$\mathbb{P}(\frac{X_1}{x_2}\leq y)= \mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq y x_2) = 1 - e^{-x_2 y},$$
so $\frac{X_1}{x_2}$ has an exponential distribution with rate parameter $x_2$ (so the mean parameter is $\frac{1}{x_2}$). This also means that the conditional pdf is given by
$$f_{\frac{X_1}{X_2}\: | \: X_2} (x_1 \: | \: x_2) = x_2 e^{-x_1 x_2}$$

Comment: Why the answer is $x_2e^{-x_1 x_2}$? I thought we are taking the second derivative of $\mathbb{P}(\dfrac{X_1}{x_2}\leq y)$ with respect to $y$.

Comment: $x_1$ and $y$ are just variable names, so it doesn't really matter. But yes, notation-wise it would have been more consistent to write
$$f_{\frac{X_1}{X_2} \: | \: X_1}(y \: | \: x_2) = x_2 e^{-x_2 y}$$

Comment: Thank you very much.